# C++ optimization leading to thread locking

Tags: c++, multithreading, compiler-optimization

I have made a program which has the following features:

This is working in a class ClassA

variables:

```
int8_t* p1; // this is only modified on thread1
volatile int8_t* p2;
```

thread1 (which gets locked)

```
while(p1 + 64 > p2);
```

thread2 (which modifies p2)

```
while(true)  {  
    //reading file
    p2 += 10;
    //reading file
    p2 += 10;
    //reading file
    p2 += 10;
}
```

Thread1 get locked at some point. HOWEVER, changing thread1 to the code below makes that thread1 is never locked.

```
while(p1 + 64 > p2) {
    printf("%d\n", p1);
}
```

I compiled this code with `-Ofast`. I guess the problem is the optimization. How could I fix this without modifying my compiler flags?

Comment: Do not use volatile for thread synchronisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use a mutex or use proper atomic types for both `p1` and `p2`. In C++, `volatile` has no defined multi-threading semantics. Modifying a regular variable (like `p2`) while another thread might be accessing it yields unpredictable results. Don't do it.

Comment: I made a mistake on the code. The volatile variable was p2 not p1

Comment: It doesn't make much difference. Don't use `volatile`. Use either atomic types or mutexes.

Answer (score -1):

p2 is the variable modified outside you first thread at it therefore should be declared volatile.

Even so, rather use atomics or a mutex. volatile does not protect agains out of order reads and writes. On linux, mutexes are very cheap when there is no contention.

Comment: volatile has nothing to do with data synchronization across threads.

Comment: Volatile tells the compiler that the memory address van be modified outside the current thead, be it by hardware, os, or another thread. So although its use is inadvisable, might help in this case.

Comment: Sure, volatile might help in this case: it might hide the real problem temporarily, and that, of course means that the real problem will show itself when you demo your code for you most important client; "well, it used to work" will not be an acceptable response.

Comment: The big problem with volatile is out of order reads and writes. Sure, you can put in a memory barrier but rather just use proper apis that take care of this for you. So I agree 100% volatile is a bad idea unless you really know what you are doing and on which platform.